# plotting dynamic array data structure with highchart

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dynamic, highcharts

I have a problem regarding plotting a dynamic data from a highchart. I have my data from ajax, and I want it to be plotted in my highcharts.

Here is what I've done:

```
function case_category_adoption() {
     let series_cases_adopt = [];
     $.ajax({
        url: baseurl+'user/get_case_category_adoption_distribution',
        type: 'POST',       
        success: function(response) {
            const results = JSON.parse(response);                                
            let res_array = [];
            for (const result of results) {                
                res_array["data"] = result.case_name;
                res_array["count"] = parseInt(result.cases_count);
                series_cases_adopt.push(res_array);
            }


            let chart_adoption_case_cat = Highcharts.chart('container-case-cat-adoption', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2017'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category',
                    labels: {
                        rotation: -45,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '13px',
                            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                        }
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Population (millions)'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: 'Population in 2017: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Population',
                    data: series_cases_adopt,
                    // data: [
                    //         ['Shanghai', 24.2],
                    //         ['Beijing', 20.8],
                    //         ['Karachi', 14.9],
                    //         ['Shenzhen', 13.7],
                    //         ['Guangzhou', 13.1],
                    //         ['Istanbul', 12.7],
                    //         ['Mumbai', 12.4],
                    //         ['Moscow', 12.2],
                    //         ['São Paulo', 12.0],
                    //         ['Delhi', 11.7],
                    //         ['Kinshasa', 11.5],
                    //         ['Tianjin', 11.2],
                    //         ['Lahore', 11.1],
                    //         ['Jakarta', 10.6],
                    //         ['Dongguan', 10.6],
                    //         ['Lagos', 10.6],
                    //         ['Bengaluru', 10.3],
                    //         ['Seoul', 9.8],
                    //         ['Foshan', 9.3],
                    //         ['Tokyo', 9.3]
                    //     ],
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        rotation: -90,
                        color: '#FFFFFF',
                        align: 'right',
                        format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
                        y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '13px',
                            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            });

        }
    });
}
```

I tried to make an array to fit the highchart data example but it doesn't work. When I tried to check the value of `series_cases_adopt` array , Here is the log:

```
(4) […]

0: []
​​
count: 0
​​
data: "Trafficked"
​​
length: 0
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
1: []
​​
count: 0
​​
data: "Trafficked"
​​
length: 0
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
2: []
​​
count: 0
​​
data: "Trafficked"
​​
length: 0
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
3: []
​​
count: 0
​​
data: "Trafficked"
​​
length: 0
​​
<prototype>: Array []
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
for (const result of results) {                
    res_array["data"] = result.case_name;
    res_array["count"] = parseInt(result.cases_count);
    series_cases_adopt.push(res_array);
}
```

You are creating an array with keys, you need to create a basic array with indexed values:

---

```
for (const result of results) {
    series_cases_adopt.push([
        result.case_name,
        parseInt(result.cases_count)
    ]);
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vncoebmx/

Comment: thank you for your response. I will try this one!.

Comment: doesn't work. Here is the jsfiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-rotated-labels

Comment: Hi @Jc John, Could you provide me with a log of the `series_cases_adopt` variable after adding the proposed changes>

Answer (score 0):

> This is how I resolved it:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container-case-cat-adoption" style="height: 400px"></div>
<script>
$(function case_category_adoption() {
     let series_cases_adopt = [];
            let chart_adoption_case_cat =  $('#container-case-cat-adoption').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2017'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category',
                    labels: {
                        rotation: -45,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '13px',
                            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                        }
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Population (millions)'
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: 'Population in 2017: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Population',
                    data: series_cases_adopt,
                                data: [

                    ['Shanghai', 24.2],
                     ['Beijing', 20.8],
                     ['Karachi', 14.9],
                     ['Shenzhen', 13.7],
                     ['Guangzhou', 13.1],
                     ['Istanbul', 12.7],
                     ['Mumbai', 12.4],
                     ['Moscow', 12.2],
                     ['São Paulo', 12.0],
                     ['Delhi', 11.7],
                     ['Kinshasa', 11.5],
                     ['Tianjin', 11.2],
                     ['Lahore', 11.1],
                     ['Jakarta', 10.6],
                     ['Dongguan', 10.6],
                     ['Lagos', 10.6],
                     ['Bengaluru', 10.3],
                     ['Seoul', 9.8],
                     ['Foshan', 9.3],
                     ['Tokyo', 9.3]
                 ],
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        rotation: -90,
                        color: '#FFFFFF',
                        align: 'right',
                        format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
                        y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '13px',
                            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            });
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]